# Binary tree insertion, help me to read valgrinds information

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, binary-tree, valgrind

after some basic binary tree insertion implemenation, I got an memory error. I would appreciate very much, if you could tell me for my future learning process, where to find the problem in valgrind. I'm using like I read in other threads or through online research `-v` or `--leak-check=full` aswell as`--show-leak-kinds=all` to find more about the memory leak.

Here is my code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


typedef int bool;
#define true 1
#define false 0

typedef struct _bstNode
{
    int data;
    struct _bstNode *left;
    struct _bstNode *right;
} bstNode;

bstNode *getNewNode(int number)
{
    bstNode *newNode = malloc(sizeof(bstNode));
    newNode->data = number;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;

    return newNode;
}

bstNode *insert(bstNode *root, int number)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = getNewNode(number);
    }else if(root->data <= number)
    {
        root->left = insert(root, number);
    }else if(root->data > number)
    {
        root->right = insert(root, number);
    }else
    {
        printf("Error inserting number.\n");
    }
    return root;
}

/*bool search(bstNode *root, int toSearch)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    if(root->data == toSearch)
    {
        return true;
    } else if(root->data <= toSearch)
    {
        return search(root->left, toSearch);
    } else if(root->data > toSearch)
    {
        return search(root->right, toSearch);
    }else
    {
        printf("Error searching for number\n");
        return false;
    }
}*/

void destroy_tree(bstNode *n)
{
    if(n->left)
    {
        destroy_tree(n->left);
    }
    if(n->right)
    {
        destroy_tree(n->right);
    }
    free(n);
}

int main()
{
    bstNode *root = NULL;

    root = insert(root, 8);
    root = insert(root, 12);
    root = insert(root, 43);
    root = insert(root, 22);
    root = insert(root, 2);
    root = insert(root, 8);

    /*if(search(root, 9) == true)
    {
        printf("Found\n");
    }else
    {
        printf("Number not found\n");
    }

    if(search(root, 22) == true)
    {
        printf("Found\n");
    }else
    {
        printf("Number not found\n");
    }*/

    destroy_tree(root);
    return 0;
}
```

```html
==3990== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==3990== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==3990== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==3990== Command: ./test
==3990== 
==3990== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801000
==3990== 
==3990== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3990==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFE801FF8
==3990== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801000
==3990==    at 0x400633: insert (in /home/richie/Dokumente/learningc/test)
==3990==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==3990==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==3990==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==3990==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==3990==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==3990== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801000
==3990== 
==3990== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==3990==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFE801FF0
==3990== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801000
==3990==    at 0x4A28680: _vgnU_freeres (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so)
==3990==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==3990==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==3990==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==3990==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==3990==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
==3990== 
==3990== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3990==     in use at exit: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==3990==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 24 bytes allocated
==3990== 
==3990== 24 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==3990==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3990==    by 0x4005CA: getNewNode (in /home/richie/Dokumente/learningc/test)
==3990==    by 0x400615: insert (in /home/richie/Dokumente/learningc/test)
==3990==    by 0x4006F3: main (in /home/richie/Dokumente/learningc/test)
==3990== 
==3990== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3990==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3990==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3990==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3990==    still reachable: 24 bytes in 1 blocks
==3990==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3990== 
==3990== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3990== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Speicherzugriffsfehler (Speicherabzug geschrieben)
```

Comment: Don't overuse code snippet. Non-JS/HTML/CSS should be formatted with Ctrl+K.

Comment: The code does recursive calls (`insert()` calls itself) resulting in a "*`Stack overflow in thread #1`*". A Stack overflow means all stack space had been used ... **bang**

Comment: It should be noted that you shouldn't use `_`-prefixed identifiers; they're reserved by the C standard. Additionally, you may be interested in `<stdbool.h>`, which has existed in standard C since 1999... Having said this, **perhaps what's most important in the process of asking about that which you don't know, is telling us what you DO know**. Otherwise, we have to assume that you know *absolutely nothing*, start from scratch and rewrite entire chapters from a programming textbook... Speaking of which, **which book are you reading?**

Answer (score 3):

The statements

```
    root->left = insert(root, number);
```

and

```
    root->right = insert(root, number);
```

cause infinite recursion because you don't change the root you pass. Instead, use:

```
    root->left = insert(root->left, number);
```

and

```
    root->right = insert(root->right, number);
```

---

Note: your `if(root->data <= number)` can create a duplicate. Instead,  use `<` and then your `Error` branch identifies the duplicate (which may or may not be an error).

Comment: "*cause infinite recursion*" which in turn causes a "*`Stack overflow`*" as mentioned by Valgrind.

Comment: is there any possibility to get an output from valgrind which is telling on what line exactly the overflow comes from?

Answer (score 1):

Small error in your recursive insert function

```
bstNode *insert(bstNode *root, int number)
{
    if(root == NULL)
    {
        root = getNewNode(number);
    }else if(root->data <= number)
    {
        root->left = insert(root->left, number);      // insert(root->left
    }else if(root->data > number)
    {
        root->right = insert(root->right, number);    // insert(root->right
    }else
    {
        printf("Error inserting number.\n");
    }
    return root;
}
```

If `root` is not NULL, you should move down to either the right or left sub-tree until you find a NULL spot to create a new node.  Your original `insert()` simply kept trying to insert at the `root`.

Answer (score 1):

> where to find the problem in valgrind.

The code does recursive calls (`insert()` calls itself instead of `return`ing) resulting in

```
==3990== Stack overflow in thread #1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801000
```

A stack overflow means all stack space is in use. And as stack space is limited for a process this situation cannot be resolved and the process by raising a signal

```
==3990== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
```

To fix this adjust the code to sooner or later `return` from `insert()`.

To understand where the stack overflow occurs compile with symbols (option `-g` for GCC) and run the code inside a debugger, `gdb` for example.